# Insufficient Privileges error when creating community user

Tags: community

I am getting an "Insufficient Privileges" error when I try to create a user with profile "Customer Community User",after going to "Enable Customer User" from "Manage External User" on the contact page.

Comment: Have you checked that you(your user record)  have any role on user record?

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this on a trial org's sandboxes. I was able to create community users against "Customer Community Plus" license type profiles, using "Enable Customer User" on the Contact, but I would get this "Insufficient Privileges" error when I tried the same against "Customer Community" license type profiles.

I contacted Salesforce who enabled both "High Volume Customer Portal" and "Lite Portal" licenses on the trial org (which I then [matched down to the sandbox](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000335272&type=1&mode=1)).

This resolved the problem for me but your mileage may vary.

BTW, to directly use the standard "Customer Community User" profile with a Digital Experience (community) you must now go to Setup > Digital Experiences > Settings and enable the **Allow using standard external profiles for self-registration and user creation** preference as covered [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000349086&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1).